# Copy data - Case dynamic path and filename sink

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have several source files:  salesYYYYMMDDfinal.txt, ordersYYYYMMDDedited.txt

I read all files on copy command using a single copy data activity, with source the variable *@{variables('File')}*.TXT  and File as the YYYYMMDD variable.

up to this point, everything is ok.

for sink, I enable the blob type so it allow me to add variable as filepath.

as sinkFilePath variable I want to create with the pipeline expression builder something like:

/salesfolder/salesYYYYMMDD.txt

/ordersfolder/ordersYYYYMMDD.txt

so, according part of the filename, it will decide the folder, and also remove: final, edited, etc from filename. just keep type of file plus YYYYMMDD.txt

Also, if this can be done on a different way, other than the pipelike expression, it wil help me a lot.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use azure dataflows as well to achieve your requirement to make this work dynamically. First use get metadata activity to get the childitems (your files).

[image]

- Now, iterate through this returned data in a for each loop. inside this for each loop I have a dataflow that accepts a string parameter. You have to pass `@item().name` in each iteration to this dataflow.

[image]

- I have taken a sample file with one column and 1 row as my source dataset for dataflow (you can take the same).

[image]

- The following is the dataflow JSON which I have used to generate the final folder name and final file name.

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText3",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     file as string (\"orders20230521final.csv\")",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          id as string",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(final_file = concat(regexSplit($file,regexExtract($file,'(\\\\d{8})'))[1],regexExtract($file,'(\\\\d{8})'),'.csv'),",
                "          dir = concat(regexSplit($file,regexExtract($file,'(\\\\d{8})'))[1],'folder')) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 sink(validateSchema: false,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     store: 'cache',",
                "     format: 'inline',",
                "     output: true,",
                "     saveOrder: 1) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

- Select sink as cache and write to activity output. In for each, after each iteration, you would get the required folder name and final file name from this dataflow. You can use these values in sink path of copy data activity.
- Output for "orders20230521final.csv":

[image]

- Output for "sales20230523edit.csv":

[image]